# Uniform HTML templating language

Tags: html, language-agnostic, templating, dynamic-html

It seems like every web framework has its own pet template language. Ruby has [eRuby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERuby), Python's [django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_web_framework) uses the [Django template language](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/), Haskell has [Heist](http://snapframework.com/docs/tutorials/heist) and [Hamlet](http://docs.yesodweb.com/blog/whats-in-a-hamlet), Java's got [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages), and then there's PHP...

My question is, has anyone tried creating One Templating Language to Rule Them All? Are there any such templating languages that at least have *some* widespread support amongst the varying web frameworks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) maybe.

Comment: Important to note that this is because it can call functions in a language-agnostic (though very limited) fashion.

Comment: It is easy for something as trivial as Mustache to come close to universal. :-)

Answer (score 3):

[XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) might be a candidate as a "universal" template language.

It might also be the greatest evil that this land has ever seen, but that's up for debate.

Comment: definitely the greatest evil this land has ever seen.

Comment: Well, it isn't universal in a way that it depends on XML as a data source - even if it can be used to produce output other than XML

Answer (score 0):

NHAML/HAML is the closest you'll get to a standard.

Answer (score 0):

**[Freemarker](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/&ei=29yOTfa4Foq-tgfHs9XLDQ&usg=AFQjCNGib2rcnIxKwpN-I35K_2vT8UV9nA&sig2=sYYD75Wdrgaksh1KuJR5sA)** (and [Velocity](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http://velocity.apache.org/&ei=BN2OTarZC4a-tgfHoqm_DQ&usg=AFQjCNFYbb0-LMEr5u2CtVbEz6EvmVVKQA&sig2=-K-g2-geNqOJ4m-J7MqYfg) to some extent) seem to be supported by a growing number of frameworks (Spring, Tiles, Struts and [more](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/poweredBy.html)) and can be used to generate code in any framework, but I don't think there is "one template engine to rule them all". If there was though, I would choose **Freemarker** any day

Comment: If I understand correctly, both are Java only? :( Though I suppose that 98% of truly enterprisey projects are in Java nowadays...

Comment: Velocity has a .NET port (http://nvelocity.sourceforge.net/) but I don't know of one for Freemarker

Comment: These are hardly choices if you need client side templates.

Comment: True, though I am not sure the OP meant to include them. if so, I would recommend Handlebars or DoT.js rather than Mustache

Answer (score 0):

uh... Trying to find something like that for WEB project which would be able to render html from same templates at both sides. Server and Client. Already mentioned Mustache seams to be most suitable choice so far...

Maybe [this](https://github.com/sandermak/embedded-json-example) JSON based solution will sound interesting...

Also [HAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAML) looks promising.